# Drupal equivalent of WordPress' page templates

Tags: theming

I'm developing my first Drupal site, having built my CMS experience on WordPress. I've managed to wrap my head around many of Drupal's paradigms, but I can't figure out how Drupal accomplishes the functionality of page templates in WordPress.

By "page templates" I mean the option in WordPress to set a specific template (written in PHP) to use for a given page:

[image: WordPress Page Attributes]

For reference, I use the templates in multi-site deployments to create standardized pages for subsites (e.g. "contact", "about us"), but a subsite has the ability to disable the template and create their own content.

What would be the best practice to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to suggest/override theme of a page in Drupal.

**1. Override core theme files:**

Firstly there are core themes defined by Drupal, which can be overridden from your theme. For example, the default user profile page uses `user-profile.tpl.php`. Though this is defined in Drupal Core, you can override it by copying it to your theme folder and modifying. The list of core file can be [found here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/theming/core-templates).

**2. Default Theme Suggestions in Core**

Drupal has implemented some default theme suggestion patterns in the core. It helps us write a specific theme for a page, path or even a particular article without having to write code. For example, if your about page has a node id 1. You write a template for just that page by creating a template file `page--node--1.tpl.php` in your theme folder. Similarly, you can suggest a theme for a node, user, block etc.  You can see available core suggestions [in this page](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/theming/template-theme-hook-suggestions) under respective heading.

**3. From UI using context module:**

[Context](https://www.drupal.org/project/context) module allows you to manage contextual conditions and reactions for different portions of your site. You can, for example, choose 1 or more conditions like path, user type etc and then add theme suggestion as a reaction to that condition/s.

1. [Using context module.](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/context-tutorial/)
2. [Also, see ThemeKey module.](https://www.drupal.org/project/themekey)

**4. From code:**
You can also write custom theme suggestion based on your own logic from code, either in template.php file of your template from a custom module.

An example from documentation:

// Add a single suggestion for nodes that have the "Promoted to front page" box checked.

```
function drop_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['promote']) {
    // looks for node--promoted.tpl.php in your theme directory
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'] = 'node__promoted';
  }
}
```

A lot of code example can be seen if you scroll a bit down on [this page](https://www.drupal.org/node/223440#custom-suggestions).

**Additionally,** change the theme debug settings in setting.php to get additional information in HTML markup with respect to the theme. The setting to change is `$conf['theme_debug'] = TRUE;`. Once done, you'll get a lot of valuable suggestion in the HTML markup of each page.

Comment: In D8, there isn't a 'theme_hook_suggestions' key in the THEME_preprocess_node argument, and adding it as done in your code sample doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Figured it out for D8. THEME_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter() has to be used to change the suggestion for a node (i.e. mytheme_theme_suggestions_node_alter())